# how to mock ngrx store.pipe with specific selector using jasmine spyon

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, ngrx

In before each I have created a store spy obj

```
store = jasmine.createSpyObj<SomeState>('Store', ['pipe', 'dispatch'])
```

In individual test I want to return a mock for a specific selector. Using `withargs` doesnt seems to work.

```
store.pipe.withArgs(select(someSelector1)).and.returnValue(of(someMock))
store.pipe.withArgs(select(someSelector2)).and.returnValue(of(someMock2))
```

The only way to mock selectors is to use `returnvalues` and return mock observable in the order they are bring called in source code, like so:

```
store.pipe.and.returnValues(of(someMock1), of(someMock2))
```

Another alternative is to use select instead of pipe in source code and spy on store select instead of pipe, like so:

```
store = jasmine.createSpyObj<SomeState>('Store', ['pipe', 'dispatch', 'select'])

store.select.withArgs(someSelector1).and.returnValue(of(someMock))
store.select.withArgs(someSelector2).and.returnValue(of(someMock2))
```

but this doesnt work when the selector takes a parameter like this:

```
store.select.withArgs(someSelector(param)).and.returnValue(of(mock))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the `MockStore`, you can have mock selectors like this: https://ngrx.io/guide/store/testing#using-mock-selectors

If you're using the actual store (`StoreModule.forRoot()`) also known as integration testing, just dispatch the actions that will change the store and you won't have to mock your selectors. Check out integration testing here: https://ngrx.io/guide/store/testing#integration-testing

With integration testing, you can just do `store.dispatch(yourAction())` where the action will actually modify the store and then your selectors will work without mocking them.